# Appending the values of the date to a directory path in a bash script

Tags: bash, directory, mkdir

I am in the process of writing a script that stores log files collected for the previous day. I would like to store these log files in a directory path from year to month to day as such: `2016/Jan/01`.

I have written the following command to determine yesterdays date:

```
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d yesterday)
```

which displays yesterdas date as `yyyy-mm-dd`

What is the best way that can create a directory and append these values like:

```
mkdir +%Y + '/' + -%m + '/' + -%d
```

and also interprit the month as the first three letters of the month `Jan` rather than the number `01`.

Comment: `mkdir -p "$(date +%Y/%m/%d -d yesterday)"` -- is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `-p` in `mkdir` to create the parent directories if they do not exist already:

```
yesterday=$(date "+%Y/%m/%d" -d "yesterday")
mkdir -p "$yesterday"
```

Note I use `/` as a delimiter in the date format so you already have the string `2016/05/24`.

Upon doing this, I get:

```
$ tree 2016/
2016/
└── 05
    └── 24

2 directories, 0 files
```

From `man mkdir`:

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks. Is there a way that the month number can be converted to the first the letters? i.e 'May' instead of '05'

Comment: Ahh I got it - %b instead of %m